# How to sort orders in report "totalsales" by subcategory in opencart 3?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

im new in opencart// in admin panel we have sales reports, but in total sales report we have only prodocts with total quantity. How to make this report better - to show subcategories and total sales on it? I find table oc_product_to_category with product_id and category_id

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [order by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause in SQL.

Comment: i found this in admin/model/extension/report/product.php    public function getPurchased($data = array()) {
  $sql = "SELECT op.name, op.model, SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity, SUM((op.price + op.tax) * op.quantity) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id)";